# Approximating a weird sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

How can I approximate the sum$$\sum_{k=1}^n
\left(\frac{2k}{n} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k} \right\rceil \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\}-1\right)$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part function, and $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

I know that if I divide by $n$ and let $n\to\infty$, it's equal to $0$.  At first I thought the sum might be of the order $n^a$, but now I think it could be logarithmic.  The partial sums are really weird.  I would appreciate any help on giving an approximate value to the sum.

Comment: I was checking numerically the values for $n\leq 1000$. Looking at the number they seem to be rather spread (both positive and negative and of different magnitude). Given that  I am not sure the an approximation in terms of a smooth function does in fact exist.

Comment: Damnet, it would be really helpful if I had one lol

Comment: @Ethan So, did you ever figure out a better approximation?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber No I sort of gave up on this a while ago, it doesn't really matter to me anymore, but just looking at it now, I would say application of the dirichlet hyperbola method, would probably give me an ok estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An observation: let $\rm f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n
\left(\frac{2k}{n} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k} \right\rceil \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\}-1\right)$ and $\rm \mu(n)$ be the mean of $\rm f(1),\ldots,f(n)$.  Then $\rm \mu(n)$ is logarithmic:

[image: log].

as is the standard deviation:

[image]

so you could probably come up with a numerical estimate for a bound *as a function of $\rm n$* pretty easily, though it appears that $\rm f$ is unbounded as $\rm n\rightarrow\infty$.

EDIT: The upper and lower bounds actually seem to behave like [those of the Divisor Summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function).  Maybe you should look at that.